# How can I open the printPreviewDialog in a tab from my Form?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, c#-4.0, print-preview

I need do that. I can't open another window, my print preview dialog need be in a tab "print preview", and I don't know how I do that.

Comment: You wouldn't.  If you don't want to display a dialogue then don't use a dialogue.  If what you want is to display a control on a form then do that, i.e. use a `PrintPreviewControl`.

Comment: But the PrintPreviewControl have problems with more pages, I didn't have the same problems with PrintPreviewDialog

Comment: Maybe you should ask a question about those problems.  Surely you dont think you are the first to want to do this?